# Continue comment while editing lisp and when hitting enter

Tags: comment, newlines

If I'm writing a comment

```
;; this is a comment
;; this is its second line
```

And I hit enter, I get a new line like this:

```
;; this is a comment
;; this is its second line
```

Instead of getting a new line with comments continued, like this:

```
;; this is a comment
;; this is its second line
;;
```

How do I get the latter behavior? I'm editing clojure if that matters

Comment: How is it supposed to know that you want to continue the comment? How is it going to know that you have finished the comment and you now want to write some code?

Comment: It can't know.  But it can be more convenient to manually break out of the comment (once) than to manually continue the comment (for every line of it).

Answer (score 2):

The standard key for this behaviour is <kbd>M-j</kbd>.  It is bound to `indent-new-comment-line` by default but, depending on the buffer, may be bound to some other mode-specific analog.  These commands take care of indentation, and also comment continuation when you're inside one.

In programming modes I make <kbd>RET</kbd> do whatever <kbd>M-j</kbd> does:

```el
(defun my-coding-config ()
  "Custom behaviours for most programming modes."
  ;; Make RET maintain indentation and comments.
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") (key-binding (kbd "M-j")))
  (local-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") 'newline))

(mapc
 (lambda (language-mode-hook)
   (add-hook language-mode-hook 'my-coding-config))
 '(prog-mode-hook
   ;; plus anything not derived from prog-mode:
   inferior-emacs-lisp-mode-hook
   css-mode-hook
   python-mode-hook))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-js-mode-hook)
(defun my-js-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `js-mode'."
  ;; Fix M-j behaviour in block comments in js-mode
  (setq-local comment-multi-line t)
  (local-set-key [remap indent-new-comment-line] 'c-indent-new-comment-line))
```